# Object doesn't support property or method 'prefixed'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 MVC4 apps.

- 1st) was build long time ago.
- 2nd) is fresh one.

I wana include this menu http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/19/responsive-multi-level-menu/

On fresh one everything works fine. No errors, menu works fine.

When I try to launch my old one - I get this error

```
"JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'prefixed'".
```

I have no clue what's wrong. Can anybody help me?

EDITED:

I did what you told me. If i run this html from notepad++, everything works fine. If i run from VS10 - error apears. ![enter image description here][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ItTU.png

Comment: Maybe your new menu is expecting a new version of ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: What is throwing the error? Is it your browser? Where is the error being thrown from? (File, Line Number, Excerpt)?

Comment: On fresh one - i have no errors and Chrome/IE/Mozilla working fine. On old one - when debugging i get error on jquery.menu.dll this line this.animEndEventName = animEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'animation' ) ] + '.dlmenu';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu requires `jQuery`, but it also requires a custom version of `modernizer`. That version of modernizer is included in the download. Make sure you load the `modernizr.custom.js` **before** you load `jquery.dlmenu.js`, and of course make sure you load `jquery` before both of those.

Comment: I edidet my post. Can you check it?